# deliveryMethod valid values

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to find options for what I think is a setting for deliveryMethod.
Instead of setting the deliveryMethod to an email, I want to have the URL automatically come up from my web application.   I don't want the user to have to go to their email.   Is this possible?
I am not sure where to find valid values to use for things like this.
Thanks!

Henry

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's possible, but not by changing **deliveryMethod**.
It's called [Embedded Signing](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-in-app-embedded/) and this is how you do it.

```
Signer signer1 = new Signer {
    Email = signerEmail,
    Name = signerName,
    ClientUserId = signerClientId, // <- THIS
    RecipientId = "1"
};
```

Comment: Note that you still need _an_ email address, although it doesn't necessarily have to be a valid one since you aren't doing delivery through email

Comment: Is this for REST API only?  We are using:  eSignature SOAP API.    I am still researching.  I am looking to open up another page from our app where the user can sign.   It does not have to be embedded inside the app.   Thanks for assistance Inbar!!

Comment: You can do this with the SOAP API too.

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-soap-api/esign101/embedding/captive-recipients/

Comment: Thanks for info!  I did read that.  This looks like it is to embed into my app.   I was looking to get a url back and just open that url, outside my application....open a new browser window.    I am reviewing in case I missed something.   Thanks!

Comment: yes, the problem is these URLs are only good for 5 minutes, they expire.

Comment: So is this part possible?  The documentation is high level with and not clear on this specific topic:     I was looking to get a url back and just open that url, outside my application....open a new browser window.

Comment: you can do this if you do that right away. You cannot store the URL and use it later.